# Regex to extract both integer or float values followed by a unit, Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to build a regex which captures all patterns inside a string where an integer or a floating point number is present before an unit of measurement(ml,mg,kg etc). My current regex only considers integers and breaks when there's a space. I want to handle these in my code.

```
p = re.compile('[0-9](?:mg|kg|ml|q.s.|ui|M|g|µg)')
x = '0.9mg is the approximate dosage'
z = p.findall(x)
print(z)
```

which doesn't work for decimals and also breaks when there's a space.

Expected patterns to be captured are:

```
Examples: 0.9 mg, 9 mg, 9mg, 0.9mg
```

Any help regarding this

Using the regex in the code:

```
mg = []
newregex = r"[0-9\.\s]+(?:mg|kg|ml|q.s.|ui|M|g|µg)" 
for s in zz:
    for e in extracteddata:
        v = re.search(newregex,extracteddata,flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE)
        if v:
            mg.append(v.group(0))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
([.\d]+)\s*(?:mg|kg|ml|q.s.|ui|M|g|µg)
```

[Try it online.](https://regex101.com/r/uie0bV/2)

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to save the matched patterns in a list but getting error "ValueError: cannot process flags argument with a compiled pattern". Will be great if you can help me to solve it. Added code in the question for reference.

Comment: The actual number extracted from the string pattern can be aquired with `.group(1)`. So try with `mg.append(re.search(newregex,extracteddata,flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE)).group(1)`. Also it would be a good idea to move the pattern from inside to outside of the loop so it doesn't have to be compiled every single time.

Comment: I tried it but it's not working. I have updated the code with some changes and now getting "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object" in the line  `v = re.search(newregex,extracteddata,flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE)`. Any idea on that

Comment: There is no `.group(0)` but a `.group(1)`

Comment: This you are talking about the previous code I posted? where `mg.append(re.search(newregex,extracteddata,flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE))` was there?

Answer (score 3):

`(?<!\d|\.)\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*?(?:mg|kg|ml|q\.s\.|ui|M|g|µg)(?!\w)`

This regex will select properly formatted numbers with properly formatted units after them, and will reject badly formed numbers or non-existent units.

- `(?<!\d|\.)` - make sure there's no digits or decimal points before this number.
- `\d+` - get one or more digits.
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - optionally get a decimal point, followed by one or more digits.
- `\s*?` - get zero to unlimited whitespace characters, as few as possible.
- `(?:mg|kg|ml|q\.s\.|ui|M|g|µg)` - capture one of the listed units.
- `(?!\w)` - make sure there's no extra data following the captured unit.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9llu95/1/)

---

```py
import re

p = re.compile('(?<!\d|\.)\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*?(?:mg|kg|ml|q\.s\.|ui|M|g|µg)(?!\w)')
x = 'Examples: 0.9 mg, 9 mg, 9mg, 0.9mg'

print(p.findall(x))
```

> ['0.9 mg', '9 mg', '9mg', '0.9mg']

[Python demo](https://repl.it/repls/AchingPertinentConnections)

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to save the matched patterns in a list but getting error "ValueError: cannot process flags argument with a compiled pattern". Will be great if you can help me to solve it. Added code in the question for reference.

Comment: @techsmart That error is saying you gotta put the `re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE` flags into your `re.compile` statement, not your `re.search` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
x = '9mg 9.0mg  0 mg .009 mg is the approximate dosage'
p = re.compile('[0-9\.\s]+(?:mg|kg|ml|q.s.|ui|M|g|µg)')
p.findall(x)
```

**output** :

```
['9mg', ' 9.0mg', '  0 mg', ' .009 mg']
```

Comment: It's not working if there's a space between 0.9 and mg in the string. Example: "x = 0.9 mg is the approximate dosage"

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to save the matched patterns in a list but getting error "ValueError: cannot process flags argument with a compiled pattern". Will be great if you can help me to solve it. Added code in the question for reference.

Comment: @techsmart Do you need the output `['9mg', ' 9.0mg', '  0 mg', ' .009 mg']` in a variable? then you can just do `z = p.findall(x)`. Also if you do `re.search` then you need to do `.group(0)` on the object. It would be better `findall` or `finditer`.

Comment: No actually I don't need all matches. I have updated the code above and now getting "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object" in the line v = re.search(newregex,extracteddata,flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE). Any idea on that

Answer (score 0):

> This answer is not just a specific solution to the question but rather is an attempt at a general solution to match strings with numbers, with or without `precision`, with or without `units` and with or without `thousand` separators in both `European (.,)` and `International (.,)` formats

`(((\d{4,}(?:[\.,]\d+)?)|((\d{1,3}(?:((\.)|,)\d{1,3})?(?:\6\d{1,3})*(?:(?(7),|\.)\d+)?)))\s*(?:[a-zA-Z]*))`

- `\d{1,3}` - selects one to three digits.
- `\d{4,}` - selects one to three digits.
- `((\.)|,)` - select `. (European)` or `, (International)` for Thousand separator.
- `\6` - select only previously matched Thousand separator.
- `(?(7),|\.)` - if-else conditional which matches precision separator `, (European)` or `. (International)` based on the previously matched Thousand separator.
- `\s*?(?:[a-zA-Z]+)` - selects a unit after the matched number with or without preceding space character.

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hp1ARl/2)

---

```py
import re

p = re.compile('(((\d{4,}(?:[\.,]\d+)?)|((\d{1,3}(?:((\.)|,)\d{1,3})?(?:\6\d{1,3})*(?:(?(7),|\.)\d+)?)))\s*(?:[a-zA-Z]*))')
x = 'Examples: 0.9 mg, 9 mg, 9mg, 0.9mg'

print([item[0]for item in p.findall(x)])
```

> **Output**:
> `['0.9 mg', '9 mg', '9mg', '0.9mg']`

[Python Demo](https://repl.it/repls/FewUnwittingScience#main.py)